# Dealing with schema changes between dev & prod

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

This may be a stupid way of doing things, but it's what my company does... We make a schema change in dev, which we must subsequently move into production with our latest builds. So we manually open up the production SQL 2008 database, using the designer to make relevant modifications, deploy new code and then hope for the best. Sometimes we forget to make a change on the prod schema, which can obviously lead to major headaches. So, surely there is a better way? Ideally we would like some free tools to help us both identify and deploy schema changes, but I am not aware that such things exist....

We use ASP.NET with VS2010 if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 8):

I advocate for [upgrade scripts](http://rusanu.com/2009/05/15/version-control-and-your-database/). Always deploy *every* change, not matter how minor, as an upgrade script. Then, when moving to production, simply run the upgrade scripts from version N to version N+1. Effectively ban all the 'visual' database design/management tools.

There are various efforts in this direction, code first ORMs, [database GDR project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd483214.aspx), [diff based](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/) deployment and so on and so forth. Personally, I find the explicit upgrade script a much better alternative on the long run.

Comment: What about this schema comparison tool from VS2010: http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=2089             It seems like it could just diff the dev and prod schemas and give me an upgrade script automatically??

Comment: That is VS GDR, powered by vsdbcmd: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd193283.aspx. My problem with diff based tools started when I used one and it was innocently offering to modify a table by SELECT ... INTO and sp_rename (which is a trick most diff tools do). Except the table had 160Bn rows and was 1.5Tb on disk. This is why I much rather use upgrade scripts, so I know exactly what happens. Besides, scripts are checked in into source control, and I can have a history of changes.

Comment: If you simply diff dev to prod (considering the tool does a perfect job) you'll end up with whatever your current dev is. Asside from the issue of change tracking and having a history of changes, you are assuming that *no developer ever made any mistake and left it the dev db*.

Answer (score 0):

See [Writing and Changing Database Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd193271.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I believe Team Foundation Server has a way to store and release database schema changes with each build.  Beyond that, I agree with Remus Rusanu.  All changes must be scripted and placed in a version script that is released with each version of the appliation.